# Jouanolou thesis on l-adic cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, ho.history-overview

Does someone have a copy of the [Jean-Pierre Jouanolou's thesis](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=90399):

**Catégories dérivées et cohomologie l-adique**

or has the ability to make a digitalization? The thesis was done at Université de Paris 1969.

Comment: it seems one needs an account with [one of these French universities](https://www.worldcat.org/title/categories-derivees-en-cohomologie-l-adique/oclc/492958036#borrow) to request a photocopy (215 pages). Perhaps an [email](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~jouanolo/) to the author will get a response?

Answer (score 6):

The thesis is now published and you can find it in HAL/TEL

https://theses.hal.science/tel-04236971v1

Jean-Pierre Jouanolou. Catégories Dérivées en Cohomologie ℓ-adique. Mathématiques [math]. Faculté des sciences de Paris, 1969. Français.